# A question about the Preimages.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $f: S \rightarrow T.$ If $B \subseteq T$ and $f^{-1}(B) = \{s \in S| f(s) \in B \}.$ Can it happen that $f^{-1}(B) = S $?

**My answer is:**

yes this can happen if 1- $B =T$ or if $B = Range_{f}$ or if $f$ is 1-1 or if $f$ is onto. am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true iff $ f(S)\subseteq B$, i.e., $B$ contains the range of $f$.

Comment: So the answer depends on $B$ and not on $f$?

Comment: @Secretly No. The truth value of the condition "$f(S)\subseteq B$" depends on both $f$ and $S$.

Comment: I mean not on $f$ being 1-1 and onto.... correct?

Comment: Depends on both.  If $f$ is onto then $T = f(S)$ and so if $f(S) \subset B\subset T$ that can only work if $B=T$.  But if $f$ is not onto then $f(S) \subsetneq T$ and any set so that $f(S) \subset B \subset T$ will do.

Comment: What about $f$ being 1-1? does it has any relation to this question?

Comment: Doesn't matter whether $f$ is 1-1.  And $f$ is onto then $f(S) = T$ and the *only* way it works is if $f(S) = B=T$.  But if $f$ is not onto then any $f(S) \subsetneq T$ so there will be $f(S) \subset B \subset T$ and for any such set $S= f^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: @Secretly No. This property  does not depend on whether $f$ is 1-to-1 or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it *can* happen. For example, if $f(x)=x^2$, and $S=\mathbb R$ and $T = \mathbb R$ and $B=[0,\infty)$, then $f^{-1}(B)=S$.

Or, no matter what $S$ and $T$ are, given a $t\in T$, and $f$ defined as $f(x)=t$ (i.e., if $f$ is a constant function), then $f^{-1}(B)=S\iff t\in B$.